AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'build_federated_averaging_process'
I am trying run my keras model on tensorflow_federated federated average function. But it gives me this error: “AttributeError: module ‘tensorflow_federated.python.learning’ has no attribute ‘build_federated_averaging_process’”.My python version is 3.10+.
Can you help me please? I am researching for 7 days but I found no solution… I am using colab and I installed tensorflow_federated.
My code is:
# starting a new sesion for TF
image_size = 224
NUM_ROUNDS = 3 # federated_datasets sayısı:: bura değişecek
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model_nn = make_nn_model(IMG_SIZE)
#metrics = ['accuracy', Precision(name='Precision'), Recall(name='Recall')]
# compiling the model
#model_nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=metrics)
#_to_tff_model
model_return = tff.learning.models.from_keras_model(
        model_nn,
        input_spec=federated_datasets[0].element_spec, ##ilk train data ile eğitiyor
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
# Federated learning algoritmasını tanımlayın
trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_return)
                              #client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))
#trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_return) #önce ilk train data ile eğitiyor

# Federated learning modelini eğitin
state = trainer.initialize()
for round_num in range(NUM_ROUNDS):
    state, metrics = trainer.next(state, federated_datasets)
    print('Round {}: loss={}, accuracy={}'.format(round_num, metrics.loss, metrics.accuracy))


I tried to install tensorflow_federated_nightly but colab gives error.

you're encountering, "AttributeError: module ‘tensorflow_federated.python.learning’ has no attribute ‘build_federated_averaging_process’", suggests that the function build_federated_averaging_process does not exist in the tensorflow_federated.python.learning module.This might be due to changes in the TensorFlow Federated (TFF) library or a potential issue with the installation.Make sure you have the correct version of TensorFlow Federated installed.Ensure that the version of TensorFlow Federated you're using is compatible with your TensorFlow version.
